# How to prevent Predictive words/correction from being disabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

How can I prevent predictive words/correction from being disabled in Xcode?

I have a Textfield and it moves up and down as the keyboard opens and closes, but when correction is Enabled/Disabled, the textfield jumps to the top of the view.

I would rather prevent the predictive text from being disabled, but if this isnt possible, how can I stop the textfield from jumping to the top of the view?

I have a Outlet connected to the Vertical Space - Bottom Layout Guide for the textfield as below :

```
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewBottomConst;
```

And below is my keyboard `willshow` and `willhide`:

```
- (void)observeKeyboard {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    }

    - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
        NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
        NSValue *kbFrame = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
        CGRect keyboardFrame = [kbFrame CGRectValue];

        CGRect finalKeyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:self.view.window];

        int kbHeight = finalKeyboardFrame.size.height;
        int height = kbHeight + self.textViewBottomConst.constant;

        self.textViewBottomConst.constant = height;
        self.btnViewBottomConst.constant = height;
        _tvChat.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [_tvChat scrollRangeToVisible:_tvChat.selectedRange];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }

    - (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
        NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

        self.textViewBottomConst.constant = 10;
        self.btnViewBottomConst.constant = 10;
        [_tvChat scrollRangeToVisible:_tvChat.selectedRange];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
```

Comment: are you using auto layout ??

Comment: give your text field vertical spacing to its top view

Comment: @FattiKhan it has a vertical space to the textview above it already. When i click the emoji button or open the predictive words it jumps up higher, and then when closed, jumps up the same amount again until its reached the top of the view, then when the keyboard is closed, it returns to its correct position.